# * regular expression operator in clojure.spec

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

According to [Spec Guide](https://clojure.org/guides/spec)

`*` regular expression operator:  **checks 0 or more of a predicate/pattern**, as this:

```clj
(s/def ::seq-of-keywords (s/* keyword?))

;; opts are alternating keywords and booleans
(s/def ::opts (s/* (s/cat :opt keyword? :val boolean?)))
(s/conform ::opts [:silent? false :verbose true])
;;=> [{:opt :silent?, :val false} {:opt :verbose, :val true}]
```

But as I understand it, `s/cat` checks a sequence.

So why `(s/* (s/cat))` is not for checking a sequence of sequence each of which conforms to `(s/cat)`.

Something like this:

```clj
(s/conform ::opts [[:silent? false] [:verbose true]])
```

Why does it act like `s/*` `flatten`ed `s/cat`? Or How can I check for something like `[[:silent? false] [:verbose true]]`?

Answer (score 1):

You do that by using `coll-of`:

```
(s/conform (s/coll-of ::opts) [[:silent? false] [:verbose true]])
=> [[{:opt :silent?, :val false}] [{:opt :verbose, :val true}]]
```

Sometimes it helps to generate sample data:

```
(gen/generate (s/gen ::opts))
=> (:aqfR6b*C/.  false  :?.03/Vu7?  false  :Y17UL0/McsI5h  true)
```

which does not match the pattern of `[[:silent? false] [:verbose true]]`

But this one should be probably closer to what you are looking for:

```
(gen/generate (s/gen (s/coll-of (s/tuple keyword? boolean?))))
=> [[:X_o.u?7i/o.dIgTy false]  [:L?*/_WY._:z true]  [:X26:-j/l2q!u-7I false]]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why does ... `s/*` flatten `s/cat`?

... because a regular expression is a *structured* specification of a *flat* sequence. To paraphrase [the Spec Guide to Sequences](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_sequences) ...

- When regex ops are combined, they describe a single sequence.
- To spec a nested sequence, wrap it in an explicit call to `s/spec`.

> How can I spec something like `[[:silent? false] [:verbose true]]`?

To spec a sequence of pairs, each of which is a keyword followed by a boolean:

```
(s/def ::opts (s/* (s/spec (s/cat :opt keyword? :val boolean?))))
```

Note the `s/spec` wrapping the `s/cat`. Now, for example, ...

```
=> (s/conform ::opts [[:silent? false] [:verbose true]])
[{:opt :silent?, :val false} {:opt :verbose, :val true}]
```

You can, of course, as [akond](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55567394/1562315) does, use

- `s/tuple` instead of `s/cat`and
- `s/coll-of` instead of `s/*`

with no need for the interposed `s/spec`.